# How to pass data in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce block

```
<span class="app-column-style">
    <apex:outputField rendered="{!ap.Status__c!='Booked'}" value="{!ap.Status__c}"> </apex:outputField>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!ap.Status__c=='Booked' && isSelectiveBroker}" value="{!ap.Status__c + ' - '+ BookingDate}">
        <apex:param name="testName1" assignTo="{!AppId}" value="{!ap.Id}" />
        <apex:param name="testName2" assignTo="{!BrokerName}" value="{!ap.Broker_Account__r.Name}" />
    </apex:outputText>
 </span>
```

And a controller extension in which I have defined the two methods

```
 public without sharing class TC_BrokerPortalMyApplicationsExt {
        public String AppId {get;set;}
        public String BrokerName {get;set;}

        public String getBookingDate()
        {
            System.Debug('=====' + AppId);
            try{
                List<Queue_Activity__c> qa = [SELECT Application__c, Time__c FROM Queue_Activity__c WHERE Application__c=:AppId AND Status__c = 'Booked' AND Event__c = 'Entry' ORDER BY Time__c DESC NULLS LAST];      
                if(qa.size() > 0){
                    return String.ValueOf(qa[0].Time__c);    
                }

                return null;       
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                System.Debug(ex.getStackTraceString());
                return null;
            }

        }

        public Boolean getIsSelectiveBroker()
        {
            System.Debug('==='+BrokerName+'==');
            if(BrokerName=='10-4 Broker')
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
 }
```

But the methods are not getting called ?

The `app` is coming from

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!apps}" var="ap" styleClass="myAppsTable">
```

What I want to do is, pass the methods parameter from visualforce. But it is not working.

What is the problem here ?

Comment: Where and how  are you calling the methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<apex:param>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) component used with `<apex:outputText>` is intended to provide parameters to the output text component for use within a message formatter:

> Within `<apex:outputText>`, there’s support for the  tag to match the syntax of the MessageFormat class in Java:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="This is {0} text with {1}.">
       <apex:param value="my"/>
       <apex:param value="arguments"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

The `<apex:outputText>` component doesn't do a server call, so there's no opportunity for parameters to be assigned to controller variables and then have rendering take place on the output.

What you'd need to do here is create a wrapper class that embeds your sObjects with the rest of the computed data that your data table needs. You'd turn `apps` into a list of wrapper class instances and precompute the dates and other values you need, and then render that data in a single operation.